# Where in Southeast Asia in July is it always sunny, without rain, and with few clouds?

Tags: weather-and-climate, southeast-asia, destinations

What are some places in Southeast Asia in July where it is sunny, without rain, and with few clouds?

I know that in the south of Viet Nam it is the rainy season then. Same with northern Thailand, particularly in the northwest.

In Singapore it is mostly hot and sunny and rains somewhat less than usual. Other places?

Comment: Do you mean any parts of Asia that are relatively south and relatively east, or do you only mean the corner between China and the Indian subcontinent? Are you looking for beaches and resorts or partying backpackers or cultural stuff?

Comment: SEA is a very well-defined geographic region. Indeed, there is an Association of Southeast Asian Nations (ASEAN), which consists of 10 countries, namely Indonesia, Malaysia, the Philippines, Singapore, Thailand, Brunei, Burma (Myanmar), Cambodia, Laos, and Vietnam. East Timor, which until recently was part of Indonesia, has also applied for membership. It may be argued that Papua New Guinea is in SEA, but most consider it part of Oceania/Melanesia/Australasia. Other than exactly these 12 countries, there is no other country which can possibly be considered to be part of SEA.

Comment: Well it's not always possible for us to correctly determine which members adhere to strict geopolitical definitions. I for one don't define my travels by such concepts, hence I bothered to ask. Now at least we know recommending cross the border into China would be a breach for you.

Comment: SEA is as well-defined a 'geopolitical' concept as the USA. It would be as if I asked about the USA and you tried to clarify asking if I meant the "corner between Canada and Mexico". I am from SEA so it irks me when SEA is referred to as a "corner between China and the Indian subcontinent".

Comment: Bali. Dry season is between june and september.

Comment: Well from the opposite point of view I recently traversed China in a straight line from Laos to Mongolia, there were incredibly vast areas to my west that I never ventured into. I was very surprised to learn from city people in China that I had been travelling in "Western China". I don't know if anybody was "irked" by my not knowing the geopolitical definitions when I believed I was quite east of the centre. Then again I can tell you many peoples' eyes glaze over when they ask me about South America and I point out I've never been there because my travels were from Mexico to Panama.

Comment: Anyway my point is that there are many well-defined geopolitical terms for areas all around the world that many people won't know the strict definitions of. But they will know the cardinal directions on a compass. So don't be surprised if somebody, even yourself, interprets some place by its literal "compass" meaning, when there may be some less obvious meaning known to many but not all people.

Comment: First you made it sound as if I hadn't been clear by what I meant by 'SEA'. Next, you made it sound as if I was some pedant who had his imagination constrained by some 'strict geopolitical definitions'. But all this time it was merely you being ignorant about a very important and well-known part of the world with over 600 million people.

Comment: Not ignorant at all. I've been to most of the countries there. I didn't even think you were necessarily unclear, just wanted to know what you considered the scope, since it seems perfectly reasonable to pop across a border into Southern China for a look when in the area sightseeing.

Answer (score 4):

In July and surrounding months much of Asia is hit by the "[Southwest Monsoon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monsoon#Southwest_monsoon)", which brings rain on a near daily basis.  Contrary to what some people suspect the Monsoon normally doesn't bring continuous rain, but is generally more common to have a single rain shower each day (normally in the afternoon). This rain can be extremely heavy, but depending on your exact travel plans is often not that difficult to plan around it.

However if you're after a country that avoids the monsoon, the best candidate is Indonesia.  July is in the middle of the dry season there, with the wet season covering approximately October and April. On average it only gets rain on a few days in July.  The catch is that July is also peak tourist season - in no small part due to the good weather!

Singapore gets rain pretty much year-round. July will have a little less rain than other months near the end of the year, but you can still expect some rain almost every other day.

Although not exactly South-East Asia, you could also try [Turpan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turpan) in China.  July is actually one of it's wettest months of the year, but even so rainfall only averages 2mm for the entire month - and much of that evaporates before it actually hits the ground anyway! That said, if what you're after is good weather to go to the beach you're out of luck here - the nearest beach is about 2,500 km away.

Answer (score 0):

Malaysia is hot and humid year-round but it has the lowest average rainfall from June to September.  Like Malaysia, Singapore’s weather stays fairly constant throughout the year, with temperatures only ranging from 30-33°C. June to August is driest.

Comment: Do you have any references for the quoted data?